# Hololens Perception Simulation sample test crashes device

Tags: hololens

The sample code for perception simulation crashes my device. The device do respond to voice commands but there is not response to hand gestures neither no visuals. I have to use WDR to reset it everytime

Link to the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/perception-simulation

Here is the source code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                RestSimulationStreamSink sink = await RestSimulationStreamSink.Create(
                    // use the IP address for your device/emulator
                    new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10080"),
                    // no credentials are needed for the emulator
                    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("snarain", "snarain"),
                    // normal priorty
                    true,
                    // cancel token
                    new System.Threading.CancellationToken());

                IPerceptionSimulationManager manager = PerceptionSimulationManager.CreatePerceptionSimulationManager(sink);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        });

        // If main exits, the process exits.  
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of troubleshooting, I noticed the control mode switches to simulation that suspends all sensors to detect human gestures which makes the device unresponsive. 
Switching it back to Default resolves this problem.

Solved !!